# Convert Control Using Cast Not Working

Tags: vb.net, casting, visual-studio-2015

i have a control named SuperValidator1 on every form with `SuperValidator` type. i want to find this control and enable it using its name because the name is consistent in all forms. so this is the code i came up with :

```
        Dim validator As SuperValidator
        Dim frm As Form = Me.ParentForm
        Dim ctrl As Control()
        ctrl = frm.Controls.Find("SuperValidator1", True)
        Dim singleCtrl As Control = ctrl(0)
        validator = TryCast(singleCtrl, SuperValidator) '< ERROR LINE
```

it throws editor error : `Value of Type 'Control' cannot be converted to 'SuperValidator'`

i tried `CType` and `DirectCast` but it is the same. according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/zyy863x8(v=vs.80).aspx) i should be able to cast any data type. what is wrong and what should i do ?

btw `SuperValidator` is from `DevComponents.DotNetBar.Validator`

thanks

Comment: My guess would be that SuperValidator is not a control, does not inherit Control, but a component.

Comment: You have singleCtrl defined as control but then trying to cast that as validator and that won't happen. You need to change the data type.... You can verify all this by doing a TypeOf check to ensure you are indeed retrieving the correct control before assigning it to your varoable...

Comment: `SuperValidator` is [**indeed a component**](http://www.devcomponents.com/kb2/?p=475).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [**`SuperValidator` is a component**](http://www.devcomponents.com/kb2/?p=475) you must get it from your form's component collection. *However* at runtime components don't seem to inherit a name, so finding the exact one might be tricky.

As far as I know your only options are:

**A)** Get the first `SuperValidator` you can find, or

**B)** Match its properties (if possible).

Either way you do it you must iterate through the `Me.components.Components` collection:

```
Dim validator As SuperValidator = Nothing

For Each component In Me.components.Components
    If component.GetType() Is GetType(SuperValidator) Then
        validator = DirectCast(component, SuperValidator)
        'Perform additional property checking here if you go with Option B.
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a test that uses a control I have on a form.  Changed your logic slightly.  Give it s try and see what results you have.

```
    Dim validator As RichTextBox '  SuperValidator
    Dim frm As Form = Me '  .ParentForm
    Dim ctrl() As Control = frm.Controls.Find("RichTextBox1", True) '  ("SuperValidator1", True)
    If ctrl.Length > 0 Then
        validator = TryCast(ctrl(0), RichTextBox) '  , SuperValidator)  < ERROR LINE
    Else
        Stop
    End If
```